# Font not changing

Tags: android, xml, text, button, fonts

**I have a problem..I use a different font,and only 1 button actually shows the text with that font...
Only the continue button actually shows the right font!!
I'll give the code,because I tried to fix it,but I failed...Maybe you can fix it:**

```
 Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/TYPOGRAPH PRO Ultra Light.ttf");

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.continuebutton);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);


        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newgame);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);

        TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aboutbutton);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);

        TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

and on xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="30dip" android:background="@drawable/pickip">


    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">



<Button

     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Continue"
     android:id="@+id/continuebutton"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
     android:textSize="32dp"
      />
<Button
android:id="@+id/newgame"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="New Game"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textSize="32dp"
/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/aboutbutton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="About"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textSize="32dp"
/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/exit"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Exit"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textSize="32dp"
/>

     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `tv.setTypface` always... you must change it to `tv2`, `tv3`, etc.

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.continuebutton);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);


    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newgame);
    tv2.setTypeface(tf);

    TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aboutbutton);
    tv3.setTypeface(tf);

    TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exit);
    tv4.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: lol i can't believe this...that my friend is the result of coding for 7 hours...:) srry for the dumb question